# Visual Studio 2017 build error with TypeScript transpiling

Tags: typescript, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm using the built-in support in Visual Studio for TypeScript so that when I save TypeScript files they are transpiled into JavaScript files.

I have the following script:

```
declare namespace myLib {
    function makeGreeting(s: string): string;
    let numberOfGreetings: number;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("bp1");
});
```

My tsconfig.json file contains the following:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [ "*.ts" ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "..\\js\\site.js",
    "target": "es3"
  },
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true,
    "include": [ "jquery" ]
  }
}
```

When I save the file, it is transpiled into JavaScript without any problems but when I rebuild the project I get errors such as:

> TS2304    Build:Cannot find name '$'. Presentation (Presentation\Presentation)    C:\Development-MVC\NET\Ev\Web\UI\Presentation\Content\ts\welcome.ts 6

I think this is something to do with the type acquisition feature not working on build but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The automatic acquisition of type definitions does not seem to be working for jQuery. There is [limited information on type acquisition here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/javascript-intellisense#Auto).

Here is another approach.

Make sure you have installed both jquery and its types. We can do this with NPM from the command line.

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save-dev
```

Or, we can manually edit the package.json file.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.11"     <----- These types will be necessary.
  }
}
```

Installing jQuery and its types will resolve the `Cannot find name '$'` error.

After that, in your tsconfig make sure to use the `dom` and `es2015` libraries. Otherwise, the compiler will output new errors after resolving the jquery one.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [ "*.ts" ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "..\\js\\site.js",
    "target": "es3",
    "lib": [                     <---- These two libs will be necessary.
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "enable": true,
    "include": [ "jquery" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In the end it was a case of installing the @types package using npm, I already had jquery installed using Bower. The tsconfig settings made no difference. I also had to add `<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>` to the project file.